# Reading prompt from remote server without loggin in

Tags: c, libssh

When trying to connect with a remote server using console, I do the following:

```bash
$ ssh someuser@10.11.12.13
someuser@10.11.12.13's password:
```

I'm trying to mimic this with the following snippet:

```c
ssh_session session;
ssh_channel channel;

(...)

session = ssh_new();
channel = ssh_channel_new(session);

if (channel == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create SSH channel.\n");
    ssh_disconnect(session);
    ssh_free(session);
    return (1);
}
else {
    puts("Channel open.");
}

char buffer[1024];
int nbytes = 0;

while ((nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, 1, nbytes, stdout);

    if (strstr(buffer, "someuser@10.11.12.13\'s password:") != NULL) {
        break;
    }
}
```

It seems the channel is open only if I'm logged in successfully. In my case I get `Failed to create SSH channel.`.

Is it possible to read that prompt, with or without methods provided by libssh, before logging into a server?

Comment: That prompt isn't coming from the remote system, it's coming from the SSH client.